# how to parse yahoo weather api data having same tag name using jquery

Tags: javascript, android, jquery-ui, cordova, xml-parsing

I am using jquery to parse yahoo weather api xml response.

My XML response is here: http://pastie.org/4695569

At line number 41 & 42 there are two tag names `yweather:forecast`,

My code to parse the XML is here http://pastie.org/4695573

I am able to parse `yweather:forecast` tag using `forecast_today_day:$(v).find("forecast").attr("day")`

My question is: How do I get two different value using the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `each()` for this.

```
$(v).find("forecast").each(function(i) {
    alert($(this).attr('day'));
})
```

to loop through and get the values. I have alerted here.